# Javafx file chooser print name of file to term

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

Hey is there a method the will print the name of the file I choose to the term
 So I open a file using the javafx filechooser  and am looking for a way to save the name of the file I opened in a string and print it to the terminal ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
String  name = new File(path).getName();
```